# Como vuelvo al menu principal en este programa?

Tags: c, funciones, array

Buen dia, estoy haciendo un programa en donde me imprima un tipo de factura de ventas de un almacen, tengo todo hecho pero quisiera saber como hacer para volver al menu principal para hacer todo el proceso de nuevo sin necesidad de cerrar y abrir el progrma.. Aqui les deje el codigo, se les agradece su ayuda!
Pd: El include de funcionesdariend es una bibloteca de funciones hecha por mi donde tengo varias funciones guardadas para ahorrar espacio en el codigo, si necesitan que ponga este archivo en la pregunta me dicen para colocarlo.. Gracias por todo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <funcionesdariend.h>
//variables globales y arrays
int n,totalDepto=0,totalT=0,diaMay,diaMen;
char sucursales[4][8]={"David","Baru","Alanje","Gualaca"};
char departamento[5][10]={"Damas","Caballeros","Ninos","Hogar","Tecnologia"};
char dias[6][9]={"Lunes","Martes","Wednesday","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado"};
float almacen[5][6][4];
//funcion para imprimir totales
void totales(float array[][6][4]){
    printf("VENTA TOTAL DE LA SUCURSAL DAVID: %.2f\n",sumaTotal(array,0));
    printf("VENTA TOTAL DE LA SUCURSAL BARU: %.2f\n",sumaTotal(array,1));
    printf("VENTA TOTAL DE LA SUCURSAL ALANJE: %.2f\n",sumaTotal(array,2));
printf("VENTA TOTAL DE LA SUCURSAL GUALACA: %.2f\n",sumaTotal(array,3));
printf("\nVENTA TOTAL DEL ALMACEN: %.2f\n",ventasAlmacen(array));
system("\nPause");
}
//funcion para imprimir reporte
void imprimirReporte(char c){
    for (int sucur = 0; sucur < 4; ++sucur) {
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 5; ++filas) {
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 6; ++columnas) {
            almacen[filas][columnas][sucur] = rand()%99;
        }
    }
}
int control=0,sucursalCiclo=0;
system("cls");
printf("                                             ALMACEN GASTE MENOS LLEVE MAS\n");
switch (c){
    case 'D':printf("                                                    SUCURSAL DAVID\n");sucursalCiclo=0; break;
    case 'B':printf("                                                    SUCURSAL BARU\n");sucursalCiclo=1;break;
    case 'A':printf("                                                    SUCURSAL ALANJE\n");sucursalCiclo=2;break;
    case 'G':printf("                                                    SUCURSAL GUALACA\n");sucursalCiclo=3;break;
    case 'N':break;
    default:break;
}
printf("                                               REPORTE SEMANAL DE VENTAS\n\n");
if(c!='N'){
printf("DEPARTAMENTO    LUNES              MARTES              MIERCOLES          JUEVES             VIERNES           SABADO        TOTAL DEPTO\n");
printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = control; j < control+1; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
            if(c!='N') {
                printf("%c", departamento[j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int filas = control; filas < control+1; ++filas) {
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 6; ++columnas) {
            if(c!='N') {
                printf("       %.1f        ", almacen[filas][columnas][sucursalCiclo]);
            }
            totalDepto+=almacen[filas][columnas][sucursalCiclo];
        }
    }
    if(c!='N') {
        printf("     %.1f", (double) totalDepto);
    }
    totalT+=totalDepto;
    totalDepto=0;
    if(c!='N') {
        printf("\n");
    }
    control++;
}
if(c!='N') {
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("TOTAL POR DIA   %.1f               %.1f             ", totalRow(almacen, 0, sucursalCiclo), totalRow(almacen, 1, sucursalCiclo));
    printf("%.1f              %.1f              ", totalRow(almacen, 2, sucursalCiclo), totalRow(almacen, 3, sucursalCiclo));
    printf("%.1f               %.1f             %i          \n", totalRow(almacen, 4, sucursalCiclo), totalRow(almacen, 5, sucursalCiclo), totalT);
    imprimirPie(dias, departamento, almacen, sucursalCiclo);
    printf("\nVENTA TOTAL DE LA SUCURSAL: %.2f\n", sumaTotal(almacen, sucursalCiclo));
    system("\nPause");
}
}
//funcion principal
void main() {
printf("                                              ALMACEN GASTE MENOS LLEVE MAS\n                                                REPORTE SEMANAL DE VENTAS\n");
printf("                                                 1. Sucursal de David\n                                                 2. Sucursal de Baru\n");
printf("                                                 3. Sucursal de Alanje\n                                                 4. Sucursal de Gualaca\n");
printf("                                                 5. Totales Finales\n                                                 6. Finalizar\n\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
if(n==1||n==2||n==3||n==4){
    imprimirReporte(sucursales[n-1][0]);
}
else if(n==5){
    imprimirReporte('N');
    totales(almacen);
}
else{
    printf("Ha finalizado");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que una parte del programa se repita más de una vez tienes que usar, necesariamente, bucles. En este caso el bucle debe encerrar la lógica del menú:

```
void main() {
  srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

  do
  {
    printf("                                              ALMACEN GASTE MENOS LLEVE MAS\n                                                REPORTE SEMANAL DE VENTAS\n");
    printf("                                                 1. Sucursal de David\n                                                 2. Sucursal de Baru\n");
    printf("                                                 3. Sucursal de Alanje\n                                                 4. Sucursal de Gualaca\n");
    printf("                                                 5. Totales Finales\n                                                 6. Finalizar\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n==1||n==2||n==3||n==4){
      imprimirReporte(sucursales[n-1][0]);
    }
    else if(n==5){
      imprimirReporte('N');
      totales(almacen);
    }
  } while( n != 6 );
  printf("Ha finalizado");
}
```